# How to use more then one imeOptions in android

Tags: android, xml, text, android-edittext, imeoptions

Is it possible to use more then 1 `imeOptions` in Android xml ? for the same `text field`.

e.g.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mywriting"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:imeOptions="autoText"/>
```

Right now it is giving me an error, saying `1 imeOptions has already been used` and I can't use any more

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: @AhmadArslan See my answer bellow if you still need it...

Answer (score 6):

Use | to combine, like that:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone|actionNext"
```

In your case, the problem is with *autoText*, which is not a valid value for `imeOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys i've seen your post while checking for an issue, which is the following:

When applying 2 IME options within the XML it works:

```
tools:imeOptions="actionDone|actionPrevious"
//Even tools:imeOptions="actionPrevious|actionNext" will work
```

When doing so: by default, the Ime shown will be the "DONE" (OR "NEXT" when using previous/next), but if you remain pressed some seconds on it, the "PREVIOUS" button is shown and then if you release the "DONE" button it will perform the "PREVIOUS" IME action... Whatever the options order.

[image: Dual IME options demo]

Smartest thing is that... if you do the same by code:

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE|EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS);
```

Then it doesn't work: you get only the "PREVIOUS" button

**EDIT**
OK this was a bad practice: if you wish to use Previous/Next, better is to remove ImeOptions and replace by :

```
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/layoutItemId" //Previous view to focus
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/layoutBBDate" //next view to focus
```

If you wish to use "Previous/Done" declare:

```
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/layoutItemId" //Previous view to focus
            tools:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/mywriting"
android:imeOptions="actionDone|autoText" />
```

**ERRATUM**

My bad.
It is the `inputType` not the `imeOptions` that can be combined.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/mywriting"
android:inputType="..."
android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: Yes you can combine them with `|` (a pipe)

Comment: it is saying error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'imeOptions' with value 'actionDone|autoText')

Comment: My bad, it is the `inputType` not the `imeOptions` that can be combined. `imeOptions` takes only one type.