# UITextView in Android (EditText?)

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, android-edittext, uitextview

I am looking for an equivalent to the UITextView (known from iOS Dev) on Android.

Specifically, I would like the user to be able to select one of multiple TextViews, be able to enter text (including line breaks) and then deselect the TextView again.

I am aware of the EditText element, however it appears like I can't set both a "Done Editing" and "Enter" button on the keyboard and I would really like to avoid to have a button next to my TextField.

Many thanks!

Comment: i think your concerned is the same as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516948/what-is-the-equivalent-of-android-textview-in-ios)

Comment: Take a look at this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3

Answer (score 5):

from the xml section , go to your edittexts , set their 'inputtype' attribute to text. This way , when your keyboard is open , there will be a 'done' button or a 'next' button if there are more edittexts.

Comment: I already tried this -- but then the user would not be able to type a line break, would he? For instance, it is likely that the user would like to type some bullet points.

Comment: Oh so you need both a new line and finish button , I do not know about that. Let me do a quick search

Comment: How about setting inputType attribute to 'textMultiLine' . Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this -- tried this already as well. This will just let my EditText expand so it can display as many lines as needed

Answer (score 3):

In Android unlike iOS, user has always the "back button"  available to close the keyboard (if that's what you mean with "deselect the textview"). That's why a "done" button is not needed if you only want to exit editing an EditText. Furthermore you can use

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            }
        });
```

to be aware when the editText is unfocused by the user by clicking another UI view.

I'm afraid it is not possible to have line breaks in the keyboard and a "next" keyboard button in the same time. My suggestion for that is maybe to make a button appear just next to the edittext when focus is in that view that works as a "done" or "next" button.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do this. You can only choose one `imeOption`. You can allow multiple lines and the imeOption `actionDone`. When you type a lot new lines will appear but you wont get the chance to make a line brak.
Here are some links to the Topic:

[How to use more then one imeOptions in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295749/how-to-use-more-then-one-imeoptions-in-android)

[Android EditText: Done instead of Enter or Word Wrap instead of Multi Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174481/android-edittext-done-instead-of-enter-or-word-wrap-instead-of-multi-line)

[Text Fields](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) (You can see that you can select only one option. Read "Specifying Keyboard Actions")

I know that is not a satisfactory awnser, but i think it helps to understand why this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a suggestion regarding alternative design patterns that allow the user to enter text and being able to exit the "edit" mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have come across similar problem while i was developing an android application to a client. They asked me to implement Textview to match IOS behavior. Android does not have such behavior but we can trick the user and enable IOS like behavior in Android. Here is what i did.

1. Create a Framelayout for each field and inside Framelayout overlap a Textview over Edit text and hide the Edit text by default.
2. Implement onclick() listeners for textview.
3. When user click the textview hide the Textview and show Edit text and open the keyboard(You have to do it through code it wont popup immediately). Once user has done entering his text detect Done button click on keyboard and detect dismiss keyboard action and also back press event. When any of those events occur hide the Edit text and show Textview by populating the textview with edit text data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hope it will be working for you. If not work please reply me i will try my best.

For next edit text: `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColorHint="#d4d0d0"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=" Your Name "
                    android:theme="@style/EditScreenTextInputLayoutStyle"
                    android:textColor="#ffff"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffff"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```